# Geometric Interpretation of the vanishing of a term in the Resultant of 2 Polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given $2$ polynomials of the form $a(z)=a_0z^2+2a_1z+a_0$, $b(z)=b_0z^2+2b_1z+b_0$ (all coefficients here lie in $\mathbb{C}$) we can calculate their resultant, which tells us if the polynomials share a common factor. I have an explicit formula for the resultant:

$$R_{a,b}=(2a_0b_2-4a_1b_1+2a_2b_0)^2-16(b^2_1-b_0b_2)(a^2_1-a_0a_2) $$

Clearly, the last term is the product of the discriminants of the two polynomials which has an obvious geometric interpretation. Is there an analogous interpretation for the case when $2a_0b_2-4a_1b_1+2a_2b_0=0$?

Firstly I thought it could be the cross-ratio of the roots of the polynomials but this turned out not to be the case. However, I still think the cross-ratio is involved somewhere. For some context, this has come from looking at the zeros of 2nd order homogenous quadratic forms.